# How do I remove multiple page breaks between rows in excel 2010?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

Multiple page breaks appeared between each row and column on an excel 2010 spreadsheet. How can they be removed?

Comment: I have used all the normal ways to remove a page break but have not been successful. Looking at the print preview of a 77 row, 2 column document it shows it would take 36 pages to print it. The first page is fine but from that point on  only 1 row is added to each page. Do I need to reinstall excel 2010. I'd sure appreciate your input.

Comment: What are "all the normal ways"? Have you "Reset All Page Breaks" from the Page Setup menu?

Comment: Using the Page Layout Tab and tried to both remove and reset all breaks but nothing happened. Under the View Tab I clicked on Page Break Preview and tried to move the breaks. The breaks did respond and I saved the document but when I went to the File Tab and to print the preview showed the breaks were still present. I tried to copy and paste it into another excel sheet but found the breaks were still present. I don't know what else to try besides recreating it from scratch. Help!

Comment: Did you notice that @CharlieRB gave you something else to try?

Comment: Yes I did but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described so far, this sounds like an issue with the print driver/setup and not the file. Excel automatic page breaks are generated according to the printer setup.

Check print properties from the File tab.

[image]

1. Make sure the correct printer is selected
2. Make sure the paper size is appropriate for the size you are
   printing to

Comment: The printer and the appropriate paper size are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but found that the title print range had become corrupted and was suddenly hundreds of rows. When this was reset the problems all went away.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot and a short description on how to access this functionality?